# Variable is undefined in component but defined in template from provider

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a component called profile.ts and i'm utilizing the variable user in profile.html via {{ user.fullName }}, which populates a value like it should. I'm getting the user variable from user.ts, which works fantastically.

When I go to access user.fullName in profile.ts it comes back undefined, even though it is defined in the template file? I'm not exactly sure why this is happening, if it's working in the template, it has to be working in the component file, right?

profile.ts relevant code:

```
public user;
public posts;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public toastCtrl: 
ToastService, public userProvider: User){
this.user = userProvider;

console.log(this.user.fullName); // Comes back undefined. Should come back as "John Smith"
}
```

profile.html:

```
<span class="infos_name">{{user?.fullName}}</span> // Shows the fullName variable, which is "John Smith"
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of the `user.fullName`? I think this is happening because the `constructor` is being executed *before* that property is set, and that's why the view is updated as soon as "John Smith" is set to the `user.fullName` property (since you use the `?` operator, first the view does not show anything because is undefined, and then when the property is initialized the view is updated to show "John Smith")

Comment: So I should just subscribe to it, and wait for the value to be populated?

Comment: When I check the value this.user, it has the values that I want. Including this.user.fullName. I can print this.user, but I cannot for the life of me get the value of this.user.fullName, without it coming back undefined when I directly try to access it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. I skipped the most basic principle of good programming design and was trying to access the variables before they were initiated like @sebaferreras said. Here is my solution to the problem, in case someone else runs into this in the future.

```
constructor(public auth: AuthProvider) {
  this.uid = auth.getUser().uid;
  this._DB = firebase.firestore();
  this._DB.collection('users').doc(this.uid).onSnapshot(user => {
    this.setUser(user);
   });
 }

  setUser(user) {
   this.user = {
    'uid': this.uid,
    'fullName': user.data().fullName,
     ...
 }
}

getUser() {
  return this.user;
}
```

Then when I'm trying to access the user object, I just call getUser() and boom. I'm done. Getters and Setters, I have no idea how I could have overlooked something so simple and so important to good programming design.